# Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (line 38, file "Code")" error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Any ideas why I'm getting an "Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (line 38, file "Code")" error?  This is my script from Google Sheets.  I get the popup asking if I want to send an email but it never sends.  The macro compiles OnEdit but not on send.Emails.  I do have correct data on line 150 in my Active Sheet.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var monitorCol = 17 // Set this to the number column you want to monitor

  if (editCol == monitorCol)
  {
    var response = Browser.msgBox('Notify User?', 'You have updated the status for this job, do you want to email user with this update?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    // Process the user's response.
    if (response == 'Yes') {
      sendEmails()
    }
  }
  }

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A150:F150");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  data.forEach(function (rowData) {
    var recipient2 = rowData[4];
    var emailAddress = rowData[6];
    var status = rowData[17];
     if (status == 'Finished') {
      return
    }
    var greeting = 'Hi ' + recipient2 + ',\n'
    var finishedMessage = 'Your Makerspace project is complete.  You can pick it up Wednesdays 11:00AM - 1:00PM or Friday 4:00PM - 5:30PM.';
    var keepMakingMessage = 'Keep making!!';
    var signatureMessage = 'UCA Makerspace Staff!!';
    var message = [greeting, finishedMessage, keepMakingMessage, signatureMessage].join('\n');
    var subject = 'Good news, your Makerspace project is complete';

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

})
}
```

Comment: What happens when you manually run the function sendEmails?

Answer (score 1):

Data Range is: `var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A150:F150");` six columns

`var emailAddress = rowData[6];` is column 7

solution might be: `var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A150:G150");`

or

`var emailAddress = rowData[5];`

Not enough information to know which.

I presume you are also missing `var status = rowData[17];`